# Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've a laptop that came preinstalled with windows. I wiped it and installed **elementary** linux distribution. Then months later I've installed ubuntu flavoured in another partition, so dual linux boot.

After that I've never been able to get rid of this message at startup:

```
Booting in insecure mode
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi - 80000000000000E
Failed to load image
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\MonkManager.efi - 80000000000000E
Failed to load image
```

I've inspected the Efi partition and it looks like:

```
EFI/
    BOOT/
        bootx64.efi
        bootx64.efi.grb
    Microsoft/
        Boot/
            bootmgfw.efi
            bootmgfw.efi.grb
            bootx64.efi
            bootx64.efi.grb
    ubuntu/
        grub.cfg
        grub64.efi
        MokManager.efi
        shimx64.efi
```

I've used boot-repair several times but did not fix the problem.

To mention that I am able to boot doing this:

- at startup press ESC to show the bios option
- press f9: boot device options
- it boots by manually selecting one of these:

  - ubuntu (for some reasons this option is duplicated)
  - elementary
- it won't boot and show the mentioned error above for these options:

  - Os Boot Manager
  - EFI HDD Device
  - rEFInd Boot Manager (maybe I did install this long time ago, can't remember)
  - Boot from EFI File (this shows me: `NO VOLUME LABEL.` by clicking I can navigate to the efi partition described above and see the different directories for Microsoft, ubuntu and boot
  - Notebook Hard drive (this launch grub, I don't know how can I use it)

I've been away from linux for a while, any idea how to fix this? I was planning to clean up the machine so if there is a solution that could involve deleting all my installation I could be fine with it (but better if I don't have to).

I'm aware of this very [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597245/failed-to-open-efi-microsoft-boot-grubx64-efi-80000000000000e) but didn't help me much, maybe it's a different problem.

**EDIT:**
Launched `sudo efibootmgr -v` from a live cd, this is the result:

```
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,3002,0001,0003,0005,0006,0008,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive   BIOS(2,500,00)................-.j.......j.A.j........................................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(4,749f000,2f800,4aec4607-34ba-4fa3-451d-befd65c8d660)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(4,749f000,2f800,4aec4607-34ba-4fa3-451d-befd65c8d660)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0003* EFI HDD Device (SAMSUNG MZMPC128HBFU-000H1)   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)SATA(1,0,0)HD(1,800,100000,3ef48298-b7e8-459f-8189-134862cd346b)RC
Boot0004* USB Hard Drive - Generic Flash Disk   BIOS(7,500,00).......................................................................
Boot0005* elementary    HD(4,749f000,2f800,4aec4607-34ba-4fa3-451d-befd65c8d660)File(\EFI\elementary\grubx64.efi)
Boot0006* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(4,749f000,2f800,4aec4607-34ba-4fa3-451d-befd65c8d660)File(\EFI\refind\shimx64.efi)
Boot0007* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - Generic Flash Disk    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1d,0)USB(0,0)USB(0,0)HD(1,2,7adffe,00000000)RC
Boot0008* Ubuntu    HD(4,749f000,2f800,4aec4607-34ba-4fa3-451d-befd65c8d660)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)  RC
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Cool I've lost access and password..good :] There is nothing important in those installation and they are outdated, If I delete everything and reinstall ubuntu would it fix the problem?

Comment: Neither of those files should be in /EFI/Microsoft. And it somehow added to UEFI, you need to manually delete it in UEFI. post `sudo efibootmgr -v`.  Remove entries: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: It looks like you have added Ubuntu to Windows Boot Manager. You need to remove it from there. But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: posted the result of `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is booting correctly despite those errors, ***IGNORE THEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***

Basically, fixing the problem requires tampering with a ***VERY*** delicate and critically important part of your installation -- namely, your boot loader configuration. You might fix the problem, but it's at least as likely that you'll end up creating a ***MUCH*** bigger problem. Is fixing a trivial cosmetic problem really worth the risk of doing serious damage that may prevent your booting the computer at all?

If you really want to risk your installation, I recommend you open a Terminal and type `sudo efibootmgr -v`. This will produce output something like this:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0007,2003,0001,2001,2002
Boot0000* rEFInd (direct)   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,276800,1f4000,de3b7563-97f5-48c6-ab7f-2f5d6d57c644)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (08-9E-01-FF-CA-4D)    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01ffca4d,0)IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0, 0RC
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (08-9E-01-FF-CA-4D)    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01ffca4d,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000RC
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Check the `BootOrder` line. That tells you the order in which the firmware is set to try the various `Boot####` options that follow. In my case, it tries `Boot0000` (`rEFInd (direct)`; `\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi`) first, followed by `Boot0003` (`ubuntu`; `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`), and so on. Chances are, yours is trying to boot a copy of `shimx64.efi` or `shim.efi` in `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot` first. This is failing because Shim's support files are missing, so the firmware moves on to the next item, which does work. (This is an educated *guess* on my part; I may be wrong about this, which is one of the dangers of proceeding!) Altering the `BootOrder` variable may fix this problem. You can do this with the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`, as in:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,0000,0007,2003,0001,2001,2002
```

In this example, I've specified a new boot order that swaps the first two items from my original entry. On my computer, the result would be Ubuntu's GRUB taking over from rEFInd as the primary boot program. Your system will almost certainly have a different set of entries and boot order than mine does, so you'll need to adjust your entries to match. Also, don't just swap things around randomly; take the time to read *and comprehend* what you're doing. The entry you specify as the first item should be a working boot program. (The `BootCurrent` entry should be a relatively safe thing to put first.) Failure to understand what you're doing with `efibootmgr` greatly increases the odds that you'll specify a boot order that will not work, which of course means that the computer *will not boot!* That, in turn, is why my recommendation remains that you *ignore* this minor cosmetic problem -- unless you know what you're doing, you run the risk of making things *much* worse!

---

***EDIT:*** Given the `efibootmgr` output, my recommendation is to move 0001 to the start of the boot order, as in:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0001,0002,3002,0003,0005,0006,0008,2001,2002,2003
```

If things are set up sensibly, this *should* get it working correctly; however, I can make no guarantees about that. It's clear from the evidence that the system has relics of past installations, and it's not clear what precisely is causing the symptom being reported. It's simply my educated guess that `Boot0001` will work correctly.

Also, Pilot6 is wrong in stating that the risk of mucking with the boot order is "not serious" -- or at the very best, we've got different ideas of what "not serious" is. I've seen plenty of posts from people who've ended up with systems that won't boot because they've deleted the wrong boot entries or rearranged the order in an inappropriate way. To an expert such as myself, these problems can be easily fixed; but to the average person, it can be a harrowing experience.

Comment: There is not serious risk. Some EFI boot entries should be removed. That is quite easy and safe.

Comment: It is not booting correctly, I have to open up the bios configuration each time, then selection the EFI I want to boot, then grub menu THEN I can  boot! I will test this in a couple of hours, thanks

Comment: @Jleo So please add output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` to your question. You have been asked to do it 16 hours ago.

Comment: @Pilot6 done. It's been 16 hours but I was away from the machine, can't help it