# Loading Windows 10 by GRUB in Dual Boot properly

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 18.04, windows-10, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in **UEFI** mode. After that I started **boot-repair** and restored **Windows Loader**. Then I rebooted and observed **Windows Loader** and pressed enter to load Windows ... You think it is end.

No, then I have faced with issue that **\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi** is not found.

I have go to the directory: **/boot/efi/EFI/Microfsoft/Boot/**, and there are **bootx64.efi** and **bootmngf.efi**, there is no **grubx64.efi** !?

```
EFI/
    BOOT/
        bootx64.efi
        bootx64.efi.grb
    Microsoft/
        Boot/
            bootmgfw.efi
            bootmgfw.efi.grb
            bootx64.efi
            bootx64.efi.grb
    ubuntu/
        grub.cfg
        grub64.efi
        MokManager.efi
        shimx64.efi
```

The most interesting that I have found the similar directory that was created by **Windows 10** in **/dev/sdc2** similar structure:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8192 чер  3  2017  Boot
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 389330 бер 28  2017  bootmgr
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      1 лип 16  2016  BOOTNXT
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8192 вер 18  2016  BOOTSECT.BAK
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 вер 18  2016  Recovery
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 бер 31 17:41 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 гру 19  2016 'System Volume Information'
```

[image]

Seams like **/dev/sdc2** is also **EFI** partition but created by Windows !?

Anyway, guys I am tried, a couple of days I have been trying  to install properly **Ubuntu 18.04** in **UEFI** mode and when I have succeed, I broke loading of **Windows 10**

Guy, help me maybe with some useful links how to fix properly loading of **Windows 10** after installed Ubuntu in **UEFI** mode. Boot Repair does not helped at all. Previously I have used Boot Repair succesfully, but only for restoring Windows MBR, for GPT sems like it does not help at all

**P.S.:** In similar question ( [Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672295/failed-to-open-efi-microsoft-boot-grubx64-efi) ) I have not got an idea how to fix the problem properly

Attachments:
[Boot-Repair Logs](https://pastebin.com/cXQPtZFa)

Comment: You should disable hibernation(fast boot) in windows 10 for dual booting ubuntu. Otherwise it may cause data lose. And windows will check disks everytime you boot

Comment: @Arun Thank you for reply, but how to restore loading Windows 10 ? ... Right now I have broken configuration for loading Windows 10 by GRUB \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi is not found

Comment: What brand/model system. Your Windows partitions are not typical UEFI boot Windows. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Should not need grubx64.efi in /EFI/Boot, but some have just copied from /EFI/ubuntu to /EFI/Boot. Windows install problably overwrote /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi with Windows boot loader. Grub normally makes it grub or shimx64.efi as some systems default boot that. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred This system is my own assembly. No model. It has the following configuration: Processor - Intel Core i7-4770K, Graphic Card - Gigabyte PCI-Ex GeForce GTX 760, MotherBoard - Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD5H, Disk SSD - 
Kingston HyperX Predator 480GB

Comment: I have Asus Z97 with nVidia GT620. But SSD is sda where grub prefers to install. I have multiple Ubuntu installs all UEFI in both SSD & HDD. Need to your summary report from Boot-Repair. Grub really wants to install to first drive or normally sda, or first NVMe drive. Often easier to disconnect other drives. And keep Windows on one drive and Ubuntu on another, but all in same boot mode, either all UEFI or all BIOS boot.

Comment: @oldfred I have installed on the same SSD (sdc, I also have different disks but prefer SSD because of speed) disk Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and want to dual boot them all

Comment: Many do install to same drive, but often better if system sees it as sda. And that is normally set by UEFI and its scan of motherboard ports. Or sda will usually be SATA port 0. But many systems put flash drive installer as sda and that confuses things. Need report.

Comment: @oldfred Report has been attached to https://pastebin.com/cXQPtZFa

Comment: Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI? Grub only boots working Windows. Or Windows cannot be hibernated, fast start up must be off, and it cannot need chkdsk. But you usually can then still directly boot Windows from UEFI , but may need f8 to get into repair console.  Do not know rEFInd, are you also using it?

Comment: @oldfred No, right now I cannot boot Windows due to \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi file missed. rEFInd I have installed for testing. It will be removed. How repair console will help me ?

Comment: I have seen others with similar issues, but there never should be a \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi, only Windows boot files in the Windows folder. I might just start copying grubx64 to that location & to /EFI/Boot which may be the real issue. Have you updated UEFI from Gigabyte. Required anyway for Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities, Ubuntu & Windows have updated kernels, but UEFI also needs updates.

Comment: @oldfred Yeah, but it is risky. First of all I want to make Dual-Boot for Windows and Ubuntu on the same SSD and then update UFEI fireware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found easy solution.

Seems like Grub Repair has overwritten Windows Boot Loader and event Windows Repair from Live USB has not succeeded in repairing ...

I have just reinstalled Windows 10 from Live USB and it restored Windows Boot Loader properly. After this I have been able to start Ubuntu and Windows properly from Grub.

If there is easier solution I am ready to listen ...

Additional thanks to @oldfred