# Grub boot not working - Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 17.04, windows-10

I've recently tried to install Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME version together with a windows 10 installation intending to have a dual boot.

The installation finished correctly with no error message but when I've restarted I found the message.

```
Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

I've tried with the boot-repair utility and I've got this http://paste.ubuntu.com/25723136/

Then after that I've started to receive this message.

```
failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not found
failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned not found
```

I installed Ubuntu with Windows, I never saw this kind of error.

Also, I've executed `efibootmgr -v` with a live linux I got this:

```
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0005,0001,0002,0004
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.S.T.3.0.0.0.D.M.0.0.1.-.9.Y.N.1.6.6....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .1.S.0.F.T.D.S.4......AMBOAMNO........o.M.4.-.C.T.2.5.6.M.4.S.S.D.2....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.1.5.0.9.0.5.0.5.A.7.1......AMBO
Boot0002* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.A.T.A.P.I. . . .i.H.B.S.1.1.2. . . .2....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.5.2.2.1.8.0. .7.1.2.2.6.1.1.0.5.3.1.1.5......AMBO
Boot0003* UEFI: M4-CT256M4SSD2  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(1,65535,0)/HD(2,GPT,ec284ade-27ec-447d-87a4-f975cdb4e564,0xe1800,0x32000)AMBO
Boot0004* USB   BBS(USB,,0x0)AMGOAMNOy.......W.S.a.n.D.i.s.k....................A.............................$..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.a.n.D.i.s.k......AMBO
Boot0005* UEFI: SanDisk PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,GPT,07476550-a22c-4611-99c5-f2c180b2517c,0x800,0xee63df)AMBO
```

I would be very grateful if someone could give me some advice on how to solve this issue.

Comment: I've seen an increasing number of reports of this problem, but I don't know the exact cause, or even if there's a single cause. You may want to check out a number of existing questions and answers, including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597245/failed-to-open-efi-microsoft-boot-grubx64-efi-80000000000000e) and [this one.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906776/error-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx64-efi-dual-booting) You might also see if my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can boot the system from a USB drive, but this may require temporarily disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: I've tried to make sudo bash, cd /boot/efi/EFI and continue with the "solution" found here https://askubuntu.com/questions/906776/error-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx64-efi-dual-booting. My in the live Linux /boot/efi is not found so I can not continue.

Comment: Also I've tried installin rEFInd but after that when I do sudo refind-mkdefault i've recieved this message.

rEFInd was not found in the boot options list!
You should create a rEFInd entry with efibootmgr or by re-installing
(with refind-install, for example)
No changes saved.

Comment: My suggestion to use rEFInd was to use it *on a USB drive,* which is not a permanent installation. The point is to use it to boot on a one-time (or short term) basis. If you like, you could try installing it to the hard disk; but that's more radical, carries its own caveats, and might be affected by whatever's causing this failure. That said, if you install rEFInd, are certain that its NVRAM entry exists, and that entry then disappears, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887210/efibootmanager-o-changes-are-lost-on-reboot) for the cause and workarounds.